# how to select latest DATE in MYSQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

i have 2 MYSQL tables that i LEFT JOIN based on the machine id column ('mid')

machines' table

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+-----+---------------------+
| mid | machineName |  ipAddress  | nid |      modified       |
+-----+-------------+-------------+-----+---------------------+
|   1 | machine1    | 192.168.1.1 |  16 | 2018-01-28 19:48:53 |
|   2 | machine2    | 192.168.2.1 |  16 | 2018-01-29 16:28:11 |
+-----+-------------+-------------+-----+---------------------+
```

'user_reverts' table

```
+----+-----+-----+---------------------+
| id | uid | mid |      modified       |
+----+-----+-----+---------------------+
| 11 | 189 |  1  | 2018-01-30 10:01:10 |
| 13 | 189 |  2  | 2018-01-30 12:11:50 |
| 14 | 190 |  1  | 2018-01-26 17:09:17 |
| 15 | 190 |  2  | 2018-01-25 15:51:31 |
| 16 | 189 |  2  | 2018-01-30 19:48:58 |
+----+-----+-----+---------------------+
```

the query counts the number of reverts the user has made on each machine since the beginning of each day and groups it by machine.

```
SELECT machines.mid as mid, machines.machineName as machineName,
        machines.ipAddress as ipAddress, coalesce(reverts.count, 0) as count, 
        coalesce(reverts.modified,'never') as reverted FROM
            (SELECT mid, machineName, INET6_NTOA(ipAddress) as ipAddress FROM machines) machines
            LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT machines.mid,user_reverts.modified,count(*) as count FROM machines
            INNER JOIN user_reverts ON user_reverts.mid=machines.mid AND user_reverts.uid = 189
            WHERE DATE(user_reverts.modified) = CURDATE() group by user_reverts.mid) reverts 
            ON reverts.mid = machines.mid
```

it works well except i want the 'reverted' column to show the latest time and date, so the expected result would be

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+
| mid | machineName |  ipAddress  | count |      reverted       |
+-----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+
|   1 | machine1    | 192.168.1.1 |     1 | 2018-01-24 10:01:10 |
|   2 | machine2    | 192.168.2.1 |     2 | 2018-01-30 19:48:58 | (latest)
+-----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+
```

i tried to replace

```
coalesce(reverts.count, 0)
```

with

```
MAX(reverts.count, 0)
```

but i get an error message.
how do i do this right ?
Thanks

Comment: Your data are not good for machine 1 AND you are trying to change the wrong column

Comment: please learn how to use aggregate functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another column and simplify your query allalong:

```
        SELECT machines.mid as mid
         , machines.machineName as machineName
         , INET6_NTOA(ipAddress) as ipAddress
         , coalesce(count(*), 0) as count 
         , coalesce(MAX(user_reverts.modified),'never') as reverted  -- latest revert 
      FROM machines
 LEFT JOIN user_reverts
        ON ( user_reverts.mid=machines.mid AND user_reverts.uid = 189 )
     WHERE DATE(user_reverts.modified) = CURDATE()
  GROUP BY machines.mid
         ;
```

Have a look at [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ee479/2) (The exact table definitions may differ from yours, of course).